# Produce a `DataSource` object for Postgres JDBC, programmatically

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection, datasource

The [JDBC Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html) recommends using a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object to obtain database connections rather than using the `DriverManager` class. To quote the [*Connecting with DataSource Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) page:

> `DataSource` objects … the preferred means of getting a connection to a data source.

How do I get such an object for a [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) connection to Postgres? I have a JDBC driver in place.

Right now, I do not want to fiddle around with JNDI like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3461310/642706) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32581833/642706).

Can I instantiate a `DataSource` programmatically within my Java app? Or must I implement that `DataSource` interface myself?

Comment: Similar: [*Configure a `DataSource` to connect to a managed Postgres server on Digital Ocean with SSL/TLS encryption*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65230311/642706)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## tl;dr

The [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html) class bundled with the JDBC driver from [jdbc.postgresql.org](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) implements [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface. Configure your database connection details in a `PGSimpleDataSource` object, and pass around as a `DataSource` object.

```java
PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource() ;  
ds.setServerName( "localhost" );  
ds.setDatabaseName( "your_db_name_here" );   
ds.setUser( "scott" );       
ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
```

Use that object to make a connection to the database as needed. Use convenient [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax.

```
try
(
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection() ;
) 
{ … }
```

## JDBC driver’s implementation

Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may provide for you an implementation of the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface.

An object of this implementation contains the information needed to make and configure a connection to the database, such as:

- Name & password of database user
- IP address & port number of database server

Up to three kinds of implementation provided may be available:

- Often such an implementation is a thin wrapper around the [`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html). Each time you call [`DataSource::getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--) on the object of such an implementation, you get a fresh database connection.
- Alternatively, an implementation may be using a [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) underneath to supply already-existing connections. These connections are handed out and checked back in, like books in a library, to be recycled for repeated use.
- An implementation may support the [Java Transaction API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API), supporting [X/Open XA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA), for sophisticated needs like coordinating the transactions across multiple resources such as databases and message queues. Not as commonly used, so I ignore this type here.

### Driver from jdbc.postgresql.org

The open-source free-of-cost driver from [jdbc.postgresql.org](https://jdbc.postgresql.org) provides all three types of `DataSource` implementation. But the authors do not recommend actually using their [connection pool type](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.html) in production; if you want pooling, use a third-party connection pooling library. And we are ignoring [the XA type](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSource.html).

So let's look at the simple fresh-connection-each-time implementation of `DataSource`: [`org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html)

#### Configuring the data source object

Instantiate an empty object, then call a series of [setter methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) to configure for your particular database scenario. The setter methods are inherited from [`org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html).

We are not yet upcasting to the interface `DataSource`, so that we can call the [various setter methods](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html). See example code and discussion on the [Data Sources and JNDI](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/92/jndi.html) page.

```
PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource() ;  // Empty instance.
ds.setServerName( "localhost" );  // The value `localhost` means the Postgres cluster running locally on the same machine.
ds.setDatabaseName( "testdb" );   // A connection to Postgres must be made to a specific database rather than to the server as a whole. You likely have an initial database created named `public`.
ds.setUser( "testuser" );         // Or use the super-user 'postgres' for user name if you installed Postgres with defaults and have not yet created user(s) for your application.
ds.setPassword( "password" );     // You would not really use 'password' as a password, would you?
```

Generally I would use these separate setter methods. Alternatively, you construct a String, a URL, with the various pieces of info to be set on the `DataSource` in one stroke. If you want to go that route, call [`setUrl`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html#setUrl-java.lang.String-).

That covers the basics. But you might want or need some of the other setters. Most of these are setting [Postgres property](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGProperty.html) values on the server. The properties all have smart defaults, but you may wish to override for special situations.

```
ds.setPortNumber( 6787 ) ;  // If not using the default '5432'.
ds.setApplicationName( "whatever" ) ;   // Identify the application making this connection to the database. Also a clever way to back-door some information to the Postgres server, as you can encode small values into this string for later parsing. 
ds.setConnectTimeout( … ) ;  // The timeout value used for socket connect operations, in whole seconds. If connecting to the server takes longer than this value, the connection is broken.
ds.setSocketTimeout( … ) ;  // The timeout value used for socket read operations. If reading from the server takes longer than this value, the connection is closed. This can be used as both a brute force global query timeout and a method of detecting network problems.
ds.setReadOnly( boolean ) ;  // Puts this connection in read-only mode.
```

If using [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (formerly known as SSL) to encrypt the database connection to protect against eavesdropping or malevolent manipulation, use several setters for that.

For any Postgres property without a specific setter method, you may call [`setProperty( PGProperty property, String value )`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html#setProperty-org.postgresql.PGProperty-java.lang.String-).

You can inspect or verify settings on this data source by calling any of the many getter methods.

After configuring your `PGSimpleDataSource`, you can pass off to the rest of your codebase as simply a [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html?is-external=true) object. This insulates your codebase from the shock of changing to another `DataSource` implementation or changing to [another JDBC driver](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng).

```
DataSource dataSource = ds ;  // Upcasting from concrete class to interface.
return dataSource ;
```

### Using the data source

Using a `DataSource` is utterly simple as it provides for only two methods, a pair of variations on [`getConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--) to get a [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) object for your database work.

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
```

When finished with your `Connection`, best practice is to be sure to close it. Either use a [try-with-resources syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close the connection, or explicitly close it.

```
conn.close() ;
```

Keep clear in your mind that a `DataSource` is not actually a data source. A `DataSource` is really a source for generating/accessing connections to the database. To my mind, this is a misnomer, as I think of it as `ConnectionSource`. The `DataSource` talks to your database only long enough to sign-in with user name and password. After that sign-in, you use the `Connection` object to interact with the database.

## Storing your `DataSource`

Once configured, you want to keep that `DataSource` object around, cached. No need to re-configure repeatedly. The [implementation should be written to be thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14872685/642706). You may call `getConnection` at anytime from anywhere.

For a simple little Java app, you may want to store it as a field on a singleton or in a static global variable.

For a [Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet)-based app such as a [*Vaadin*](https://www.Vaadin.com/) app, you would create a class implementing `ServletContextListener` interface. In that class your would establish your `DataSource` object when your web app is launching. From there you would store the object in the [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object by passing to [`setAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). `Context` is the technical term for 'web app'. Retrieve by calling `getAttribute` and casting to `DataSource`.

In an enterprise scenario, the `DataSource` may be stored in a [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface)-compliant implementation. Some [Servlet containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) may provide a JNDI implementation. Some organizations use a server such as an [LDAP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol). Registering & retrieving your `DataSource` object with JNDI is covered in many other Questions & Answers on Stack Overflow.