# Error "org.postgresql.Driver is not a valid javax.sql.DataSource implementation" that doesn`t affect anything. How to remove it?

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I want to go from a TomeEE server to WildFly. I have aplication that uses postgresql db.

According to different tutorials I
1) Deployed driver to the server
2) Registered it in data sources.

[image]

Connection test is successful.

When I try to start a project I get the following error:

```
09:18:45,442 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.data-source.PostgresDS" => "WFLYJCA0033: Error during the deployment of PostgresDS
    Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: WFLYJCA0030: unable to deploy
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.controller.OperationFailedException: WFLYJCA0117: org.postgresql.Driver is not a valid javax.sql.DataSource implementation [ \"WFLYJCA0117: org.postgresql.Driver is not a valid javax.sql.DataSource implementation\" ]"}}
09:18:45,443 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
```

But everything work correctly! What causes this error and can I remove it?

P.S. I have a dependency im pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitJTA" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            ...
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: `Datasource <> Driver`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091981/produce-a-datasource-object-for-postgres-jdbc-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-cpds.html) the class for the DataSource implementation provided by the Postgres JDBC driver is: `org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource`

You need to configure *that* classname for the in the "Datasource Class" property.