# How to set up JNDI DataSource with PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jndi

I am learning Java EE. My instructor told me to implement JNDI DataSource in my learning project. I have found some articles on the subject but I can't see clearly the steps to doing this.

My training project is a Spring MVC application. On the front end it has some Thymeleaf templates, and the data are taken from a PostgreSQL database.

What should be done to implement JNDI here? I don't even know why I need it. I was only told that this configuration should be considered obsolete and low-level, but I have no idea why.

Now the database is configured as follows:

- a props file with the following content:

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/trainingproject
dbuser=postgres
dbpassword=Password
```

- a .sql file which looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    row1 SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    row2 CHARACTER VARYING(64)
);
```

- a DataSource bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource datasource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(USER));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `PGSimpleDataSource` implementation of `DataSource` is bundled with JDBC driver.

The [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for Postgres at https://jdbc.postgresql.org includes an implementation of `DataSource`: `PGSimpleDataSource`

```
PGSimpleDataSource ds = new PGSimpleDataSource() ;  
ds.setServerName( "localhost" );  
ds.setDatabaseName( "your_db_name_here" );   
ds.setUser( "scott" );       
ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
```

For more info:

- The Javadoc for [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html).
- The Javadoc [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html).
- [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091982/642706) to the Question, [*Produce a `DataSource` object for Postgres JDBC, programmatically*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45091981/642706)
- The [JDBC driver’s manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html).

## JNDI

Your question conflates two issues: `DataSource` and `JNDI`.

A [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) is a simple object holding all the connection info needed to make a connection to a database. This includes a username, a password, the address of the database server, and any number of standard and proprietary feature settings. By *proprietary*, I mean Postgres-specific feature settings versus Microsoft SQL Server-specific versus Oracle-specific, etc. Look at the Javadoc for [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) to see how simple it is, basically just a [`getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()) method. You can obtain a `DataSource` object with or without JNDI; the two are orthogonal issues.

[JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) is much more complex. JNDI is an interface for obtaining from a [naming/directory server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) the configuration info needed by your app at runtime. Using this interface to such a server means you need not include deployment details in your codebase; you look up needed details on-the-fly at runtime.

Database connection info is but one of many kinds of info you might want to obtain from a JNDI server. You might also look up [web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) servers, [logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging_(software)) services, and so on.

So rather than hard-coding your database connection info, you might want to “discover” the proper database connection info when launching your app. Your testing machines will use a bogus database server while your production deployment machines will use a different database server. These database servers may not be known to the programmer at compile time, or may not even exist yet. A look-up needs to be done, and JNDI is a standard way to do so without vendor lock-in.

How you configure database connection info to be delivered by a JNDI-compliant naming/directory server as a `DataSource` object to your app differs wildly depending on the particular server environment of your enterprise. Given your last code example, it looks like you are not actually accessing a JNDI server in your class, so JNDI is moot.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it right that only the DataSource bean should be replaced of all those configuration elements that I mentioned, and the rest (.sql file, .properties file, WebConfiguration and so on) can be kept as they are?

Comment: @Danny I added another section (*JNDI*) which may address your comment's question. I avoid Spring, so I cannot help you much more than that.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. Yes, there is no JNDI server so far in this training project. But it will work without a server as well, right?

Comment: I don't like Spring so far either but it's a part of my course. Perhaps I will get to like it one day...

Comment: @Danny The `DataSource` object lives independently of JNDI. You can instantiate a `DataSource` object programmatically as I showed in my Answer. Or you can ask a properly-configured JNDI server to hand you a `DataSource` object at runtime. Perhaps a third possibility is having Spring hand you a `DataSource` object, which I guess is what your last code example does. I do not use Spring, so I can only speculate there. I would *guess* that you might alter the contents of your `@Bean public DataSource datasource()` method with something like the code shown in my Answer.