# How to connect PostgreSQL with JavaFX

Tags: java, postgresql, user-interface, javafx, jdbc

I want to connect my PostgreSQL database to JavaFX in a way that when the user enters the command in the text field, the label or the table view displays the query result. Here is my code for that which I receive a null connection error.

P.S. The picture of the UI which I have added may explain the situation better

```
public class ListController {

    @FXML
    public TextField sqlTextField;
    @FXML
    public Label textLabel;

    public void handleSaveButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    }

    public void handleRunButton(ActionEvent actionEvent1) throws SQLException {

        ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        Connection connection = connectionClass.getConnection();

        String sql = sqlTextField.getText() + ";";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            textLabel.setText(resultSet.getString(1));

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Study a [Postgres JDBC tutorial](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) and make sure you can get that work independent if the UI and JavaFX.

Comment: Study the [*JDBC Database Access*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html) tutorial by Oracle, free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you meant by `ConnectionClass`.

In JDBC, use an implementation of [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) to get connections to your database.

[This JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) for Postgres provides [a couple of implementations](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-ds.html). You likely will want `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`.

```java
PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();

String[] serverAddresses = { "your-server-address-goes-here" };
dataSource.setServerNames( serverAddresses );
int[] serverPortNumbers = { your-port-number-goes-here };
dataSource.setPortNumbers( serverPortNumbers );
dataSource.setSslCert( cert );
dataSource.setDatabaseName( "your-database-name" );
dataSource.setUser( "your-database-user-name" );
dataSource.setPassword( "your-password-goes-here" );

return dataSource ;  // Return as a `DataSource` type of object.
```

Your code elsewhere can ask for a connection. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close your connection (and other resources such as result set).

```java
try (
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
)
{
    // … Use `conn` Connection object to access database.
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230312/642706) for more discussion.

Of course, embedding your database password within your JavaFX app is insecure. One alternative is using [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) to access a service such as an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server to obtain database credentials. But that is a whole other discussion.

Also insecure is blindly executing SQL statements typed by a user. That should *never* be done in a real system. Learn about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. But if you are just experimenting, have fun.